# leider nein oder leider nicht?

Tags: difference, meaning, negation

Was ist die richtige Antwort auf diese Fragen:

> Q. Kann man die Prüfung bei Ihnen ablegen?
>   Q. Gibt es einen Terminkalender?
>
> A. Leider *nein* **oder** leider *nicht*.

Welche Antwort ist richtig? Die Sekretärin am Telefon hat mit *leider nein* geantwortet. Hätte sie nicht mit *leider nicht* antworten sollen?

Meine Intuition ist, *leider nicht* bedeutet:

> Man kann die Prüfung bei uns *leider nicht* ablegen.
>   Es gibt einen Terminkalender *leider nicht* oder es gibt *leider keinen* Terminkalender.

Was ist der Unterschied zwischen den beiden?

Comment: Unabhängig von dem "leider", sind dies "ja oder nein"-Fragen. Wie lautet wohl die korrekte Antwort auf eine solche zu verneinende Fragen? "Nein". Betrachte es als "Antwortspartikel". Das Wörtchen "nicht" dagegen ist ein "Negationspartikel" und negiert den Sachverhalt.

Comment: Ein Nomen kann nicht mit "nicht" negiert werden. Aus "einem Terminkalender" wird "kein Terminalkalender". Die Deklination ist richtig, somit ist im letzten Beispiel dein zweiter Satz richtig, aber halt nur dieser.

Comment: @Em1 d.h. *leider nicht* ist für die beiden Fällen falsch. Wo kann man *leider nicht* anwenden? Kannst du bitte ein Paar Beispiele nennen?

Comment: Ich habe den Verdacht, dass *leider nicht* als Verkürzung von *(das ist) leider nicht (möglich)* durchaus zulässig sein könnte?

Comment: _Nein, leider nicht._

Comment: @Infinity Dein Beispiel "Man kann die Prüfung bei uns leider nicht ablegen" ist korrekt.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Beide Varianten sind vollkommen korrekt.

### Leider nein

Geschlossene Fragen, die keine Verneinung enthalten, kann man streng genommen nur mit »ja« oder »nein« beantworten:

> Haben Sie diese Schuhe auch in Größe 42?
>   Nein.

Wenn die antwortende Person ihr Bedauern darüber ausdrücken will, dass die Antwort »nein« ist, kann sie die Antwort mit einem Satz ergänzen, in dem das Wort »leider« (oder ein sinnverwandter Begriff) vorkommt:

> Nein. Leider sind von diesem Model alle Exemplare der Größe 42 ausverkauft.

Das kann man auch in einem Satz zusammenfassen:

> Nein, leider sind von diesem Model alle Exemplare der Größe 42 ausverkauft.

Da die zusätzlichen Informationen in Wahrheit redundant sind (sie stecken schon in der Frage und dem »nein«), werden sie häufig weggelassen. Was übrig bleibt, ist das Wort »leider« als Ausdruck des Bedauerns:

> Haben Sie diese Schuhe auch in Größe 42?
>   Nein, leider.

Eine dermaßen verkürzte Phrase nennt man eine *Ellipse*.

Gängiger ist aber die umgekehrte Reihenfolge:

> Haben Sie diese Schuhe auch in Größe 42?
>   Leider nein.

Man kann diese Antwort auch als Verkürzung von

> Leider lautet meine Antwort »nein«.

verstehen.

---

### Leider nicht

Auch diese Antwort ist überall dort möglich und korrekt, wo ein *Nein* mit Bedauern ausgedrückt werden soll.

> Haben Sie auch Birneneis?
>   Nein, leider haben wir das nicht.

In einer verkürzten Ellipse wird daraus:

> Haben Sie auch Birneneis?
>   Nein, leider nicht.

Da das *Nicht* ebenso wie das *Nein* eine negative Antwort signalisiert, kann man das *Nein* weglassen:

> Haben Sie auch Birneneis?
>   Leider nicht.

Diese Formulierung ist ebenso üblich wie »Leider nein«, und ebenso verständlich.

---

### Leider

Beide Varianten kann man noch weiter verkürzen, zu einer Ein-Wort-Ellipse, die zugleich die Verneinung als auch den Ausdruck des Bedauerns transportiert:

> Gibt es diesen Hut auch in Dunkelgrau?
>   Leider.

Es gibt aber Situationen, wo »leider« stattdessen »ja« bedeuten kann:

> Ist das wirklich alles?
>   Leider.

Der Unterschied erschließt sich leicht aus dem Kontext: Jene Antwort (entweder »ja« oder »nein«), die geeignet ist den Fragesteller zu enttäuschen, ist jene, die mit »leider« verknüpft wird.

Es macht aber wenig Sinn, auf Fragen, bei denen beiden Antworten wenig Emotionen erwarten lassen, mit »Leider« zu antworten:

> Wäre es besser, erst an der übernächsten Kreuzung abzubiegen?
>   Leider.

Wie man bemerkt, macht es keinen Sinn, auf eine solche Frage mit »leider« zu antworten. Der Grund: Es gibt keinen Grund etwas zu bedauern, daher ruft die Antwort hauptsächlich Verwirrung hervor.

Auch das ruft Verwirrung hervor:

> Warst du schon mal in Vietnam?
>   Leider.

Es gibt nämlich zwei Möglichkeiten, das zu interpretieren:

> Leider ja. Mir wurde mein ganzes Geld gestohlen, und das Hotel war total dreckig.
>   Leider nein. Ich würde dieses Land echt gerne mal bereisen.

Zwar drückt auch hier der Fragesteller sein Bedauern aus, jedoch nicht, weil seine Antwort den Fragesteller enttäuschen könnte, sondern weil er selbst Enttäuschung empfindet. Da der Fragesteller ohne zusätzliche Informationen nicht wissen kann, was den Antwortgebenden enttäuscht, ist die Antwort »Leider« hier unzureichend.

Comment: "Leider" bedeutet immer "Leider Ja". Das Beispiel mit Vietnam ist eindeutig.

Comment: @Em1: Nach einem sehr langem Abend spricht Walter mit schwerer Zunge zu seinem Kumpanen Rüdiger: »Scheiße. Jetzt bin ich komplett blank. Hast du noch Geld für ein Taxi?« Rüdiger stochert mit trübem Blick in seiner Geldbörse rum, blickt dann Walter an, schwankt dabei kurz, und sagt: »Leider«. Deiner Hypothese zufolge würde das »ja« bedeuten. Ich bin davon aber nicht besonders überzeugt.

Comment: Vielleicht ist die Verwendung regional unterschiedlich. Bei uns im Südwesten Deutschlands würde man *Leider* nämlich immer als *Ja* verstehen, auch in obigem Beispiel.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Rüdiger würde gar nicht erst nur "leider" sagen, und sagt er doch nur "leider", ist er frustriert, dass er derjenige ist, der jetzt wieder zahlen muss ;)

Comment: Für mein (süddeutsches) Sprachgefühl ist *leider* als Kurzfassung von *leider nein* ebenfalls nicht Standard - auch wenn es aus der Situation heraus natürlich verständlich ist. Vielleicht ist es ja in manchen Regionen aus negationslosen Formulierungen wie "Da muss ich Sie leider enttäuschen" entstanden.

Comment: Ich versteh das auch sofort als "leider ja" (und leider, weil ich den anderen jetzt wohl einladen muss). Komme übrigens aus auch aus dem Südwesten.

Comment: In diesem Sinne könnte man auch das erste Beispiel mit dem Hut als "Leider ja" deuten, nämlich dann, wenn der antwortende graue Hüte total hässlich findet...

Comment: Um das nicht nur auf Südwest-Verständnis zu beschränken: Auch als Berliner verstehe ich definitiv ohne negierenden Zusatz unter "Leider." ein "Leider *ja*."

Comment: Ich bin Schweizer und würde auch 100% ja interpetieren, auch im Beispiel von @HubertSchölnast mit der Geldbörse. Ist damit "nein" gemeint, muss dies in einem echten Gesprächt mit starken non-verbalen Signalen ausgedrückt werden - und deshalb in Textform explizit daraufhingewiesen werden.

Comment: In deinem Beispiel @HubertSchölnast könnte z.B. sein, dass Rüdiger lieber nicht das Taxi bezahlen will, es jedoch trotzdem tun wird weil er genug Geld hat und ein guter Freund von Walter ist.

Answer (score 4):

Ich halte beide Antworten für richtig und sehe keinen wesentlichen Unterschied in der Bedeutung. Der [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/leider) listet beide Formulierungen als Antwort auf die Frage »Hast du Zeit?«

1) Auf Ja/Nein-Fragen kann man schlicht mit **„Ja“ oder „Nein“** antworten. Das lässt sich mit Adverbien dekorieren (vielleicht, sicher, keineswegs, ständig, möglicherweise, leider, nie). 
Manchmal erübrigt dabei sogar die eigentliche Antwort (Ja oder Nein), sodass nur noch das Adverb übrigbleibt: „Sicher“, „Vielleicht“, „Leider“.

2) Alternativ kann man die **Frage als Aussage wiederholen** und dabei gegebenenfalls ganz oder teilweise negieren:

> - Wir haben keinen Terminkalender [mehr].
> - Wir haben [sogar] zwei Terminkalender.
> - Einen Terminkalender haben wir [leider] nicht.

Wegen der hohen Redundanz sind hier Ellipsen durchaus gebräuchlich. Oft kann eine Negation auf das Wort *nicht* reduziert werden, das aber alleine noch keinen gültigen Antwortsatz ausmacht. Erst in Verbindung mit einem Adverb (oder mehr) wird daraus richtiges Deutsch: „Keinen mehr“, „Sogar zwei!“, „Leider nicht“. Die erste Antwort geht etwas an der Frage vorbei, weil ja nicht nach der Anzahl gefragt wurde. Die zweite Antwort bringt die Anzahl als Zusatzinformation mit ein, und die dritte drückt etwas Bedauern aus.

Kurzum:

- „Leider nein“ ist ein ausgeschmücktes „Nein“.
- „Leider nicht“ ist die Essenz der zur Antwort umformulierten Frage.

Answer (score 2):

Es ist grammatikalisch unerheblich für die Antwort, ob ein *leider* dabeisteht oder nicht. Denken wir es uns weg:

> Kann man die Prüfung bei Ihnen ablegen? – Nein.
>
> Gibt es einen Terminkalender? – Nein.

In beiden Fällen wäre die Antwort *nicht* falsch. Demnach ist *leider nein* auf jeden Fall eine korrekte Antwort auf die Frage.

Ich sage *eine* absichtlich, denn man kann die Frage natürlich auch in ganzen Sätzen beantworten:

> Kann man die Prüfung bei Ihnen ablegen? – Bei mir können Sie die Prüfung *nicht* ablegen.
>
> Gibt es einen Terminkalender? – Es gibt *keine* Terminkalender.

Auch in diesen Fällen kann man ein *leider* einfügen, und im ersten Fall *und nur im ersten* kann man »Leider nicht.« in der Antwort als Verkürzung des Ganzsatzes verstehen:

> Kann man die Prüfung bei Ihnen ablegen? – (Bei mir können Sie die Prüfung) leider nicht (ablegen).

Ich würde aber dennoch *leider nein* bevorzugen. Für die Terminkalender ist *leider nicht* die falsche Wahl. (Es sei denn, man argumentiert mit »(Den gibt es) leider nicht«; Danke an Dirk.)

Und dann gibt es noch die Fragen, die *noch nicht* oder *nicht mehr* als Antwort ermöglichen oder gar fordern; dort muss es natürlich entsprechend *leider noch nicht* oder *leider nicht mehr* heißen.

> Gibt es noch Terminkalender? – Nicht mehr.
>
> Sind die Prüfungsergebnisse schon da? – Noch nicht.

---

Wenn man das Revier der Grammatik verlässt, und die Höflichkeit zwischen Menschen mitbedenkt, sollte das *leider* natürlich nicht als entbehrlich gesehen werden.

Comment: Danke für die ausführliche Antwort :)

Comment: @Infinity Anstelle von Dankeschöns freut man sich auf Stackexchange über Upvotes ;)

Comment: Auch wenn es für einige doof klingt, kann man auf die Frage `Gibt es einen Terminkalender?` durchaus mit `(Den gibt es) leider nicht.` antworten. Wobei hier auch das Empfinden eine Rolle spielt. Ein `Nein` wird als Festlegen eines Sachverhaltes empfunden, wohin gegen ein `Nicht` zwar die gleiche Bedeutung hat, es einem aber das Gefühl gibt, als gäbe es eine Alternative / einen anderen Weg etc. Für eine Sekretärin die möglicht viele Anrufe in kurzer Zeit abwickeln muss, ist es mit `Nein` wohl einfacher. Das höfliche `leider` schwächt es zudem gut ab. :)

Comment: @DirkReichel Guter Punkt, das ist mir erst einmal gar nicht aufgefallen. Hab die entsprechende Passage etwas abgeschwächt.

Answer (score 0):

Auf geschlossene Fragen (wahr/falsch) wird meines Wissens mit "Ja" oder "Nein" geantwortet, das "Leider" ist belanglos dafür(?).

Comment: Es ist belanglos für das Ergebnis, nicht aber für die Interaktion mit dem fragenden. Ein bisschen Freundlichkeit ist selten falsch.

Comment: @Burki: Wie ich die Antwort verstehe, versucht sie zu argumentieren, daß _Leider nicht_ falsch sei (was falsch ist, daher –1).